# Tuning SQL query. How to change IN to something that is faster

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a website that is running a query off to Mysql when a search term is entered. I built a sql statement like this

```
SELECT * FROM catelogue
WHERE `DEPARTMENT` LIKE 'MUSIC'
AND ( `ARTIST` LIKE '%$theValue%' OR `TITLE` LIKE '%$theValue%' OR 
    `CAT NO.` IN 
    (SELECT `TRACKLISTING CAT NO.`
    FROM tracklisting 
    WHERE `ARTIST` LIKE '%$theValue%' OR `TRACK TITLE` LIKE '%$theValue%'))
    ORDER BY `RELEASEDATE` DESC
```

It worked great on wamp locally when testing. Now I have uploaded the site to my host and the query seems to be crashing or slowing it down that it doesn't even load the page.

I redesigned the query to this

```
SELECT `ARTIST` , `TITLE` , `CAT NO.` , `FORMAT` , `DEPARTMENT` , `SELL`,`IMAGE PATH` 
        FROM catelogue
WHERE `DEPARTMENT` LIKE 'MUSIC'
AND ( `ARTIST` LIKE '%$theValue%' OR `TITLE` LIKE '%$theValue%') 
    ORDER BY `RELEASEDATE` DESC"
```

As this stands it works great on my host now but I can't search my tracklisting table. I need to know how to change IN to something that works faster.

The catelogue and tracklisting table are linked by the CAT NO.

Thanks

**EDIT**

A BIG THANKS TO EVERYONE THAT HELPED

Now onto some bad news. This is the code I'm using now. It doesn't return any errors but it also doesn't return any results either

```
SELECT c.`ARTIST` , c.`TITLE` , c.`CAT NO.` , c.`FORMAT` , c.`DEPARTMENT` , c.`SELL` 
FROM    catelogue c
LEFT JOIN   tracklisting t
        ON  t.`TRACKLISTING CAT NO.` = c.`CAT NO.`
WHERE   'DEPARTMENT' = 'MUSIC'
        AND ((  c.`ARTIST` LIKE '%$theValue%' OR c.`TITLE` LIKE '%$theValue%')
                OR
                (t.`ARTIST` LIKE '%$theValue%' OR t.`TRACK TITLE` LIKE '%$theValue%'))
```

The tracklisting table doesn't have all the tracklistings for every entry in the catelogue table. Would that make a difference?

I know in ms access you can setup relationships with tables, but I have been unable to figure out if this can be done in phpmyadmin, do I have to setup a relation between the tables for this to work?

Many Thanks

Comment: Well, the fact that the trackinglist table doesn't contain everything the catelogue table does, should not be any cause for alarm. If the situation were reversed, then you would have some cause for concern. If the catelogue didn't contain everything then we would need to reverse the join.

Comment: I believe the problem is that you have 'DEPARTMENT' = 'MUSIC'. Unfortunately 'DEPARTMENT' does not in fact = 'MUSIC'. You meant `DEPARTMENT` = 'MUSIC'.

Comment: eh.... that DEPARTMENT should have had the little whateverthatthingiscalled around it. Apparently that does formatting on stackoverflow comments.

Comment: Apparently it's my fault because I did it that way in the code I posted.

Comment: I'm so (words that cannot be used) stupid. It works now with those other thingys(the console button in counterstrike). Telarian thanks so much, I kept missing that every time

Comment: Glad I could help. Sorry I screwed you up.

Comment: It's fine we all make Mistakes. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I don't really do PHP so some of your syntax is a little foreign to me but sql is sql and I've just copied the bits I'm not used to.

This should do what you want:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    catelogue c
    LEFT JOIN   tracklisting t
        ON  t.`TRACKLISTING CAT NO.` = c.`CAT NO.`
WHERE   `DEPARTMENT` = 'MUSIC'
        AND ((  c.'ARTIST' LIKE '%$theValue%' OR c.'TITLE' LIKE '%$theValue%')
                OR
                (t.`ARTIST` LIKE '%$theValue%' OR t.`TRACK TITLE` LIKE '%$theValue%'))
ORDER BY    `RELEASEDATE` DESC
```

By the way, the field naming in this database is just terrifying IMHO. It would also probably help if you could do some form of full text indexing so that these "contains" LIKE comparisons don't cause you to do full table scans every time. Just a thought.

Comment: "Just a thought." --- it shouldn't be "just", it should be the only thought that would help OP ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use join the two tables instead of using in clause:

```
SELECT 
    C.`ARTIST` , 
    C.`TITLE` , 
    C.`CAT NO.` , 
    C.`FORMAT` , 
    C.`DEPARTMENT` , 
    C.`SELL`, 
    C.`IMAGE PATH` 
FROM catelogue C LEFT JOIN tracklisting T
    ON C.`CAT NO.` = T.`TRACKLISTING CAT NO.`
WHERE 
    C.`DEPARTMENT` = 'MUSIC'
    AND (C.`ARTIST` LIKE C.'%$theValue%' OR C.`TITLE` LIKE '%$theValue%') 
    AND (T.`ARTIST` LIKE T.'%$theValue%' OR T.`TRACK TITLE` LIKE '%$theValue%')
ORDER BY 
    `RELEASEDATE` DESC
```

Note that I changed first condition from LIKE to = (faster) and consider that performance is affected by availability of indexes and by the structure of your query; for example you can:

- evaluate if you can do likes without the first %
- if so, you can add an indexes on C.`ARTIST` and C.`TITLE` and one on T.`ARTIST` and T.`TRACK TITLE`
- add an index on C.`DEPARTMENT`

Comment: It's important that you use LEFT JOIN rather than INNER JOIN or you won't get quite what you're expecting.

Comment: Right. I didn't see the OR ... IN and implemented an AND .. IN instead. Edited. Thanks.

Comment: The join returns no results, what do you think I could be doing wrong?

Comment: I think your CAT NO in TRACKINGLIST table is named `TRACKLISTING CAT NO.`. Rename column or, more likey if you don't intend to adopt a more useful naming, change the query accordingly (the ON clause becomes ON C.`CAT NO.` = T.`TRACKLISTING CAT NO.`. I based my response on your sentence 'The catelogue and tracklisting table are linked by the CAT NO'. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't tested this query, but I think its a good start. Use LEFT join insted of your structure:

```
SELECT * FROM catelogue  c
LEFT JOIN  tracklisting  t
ON c.`CAT NO.` = t.`TRACKLISTING CAT NO.`
WHERE c.`DEPARTMENT` LIKE 'MUSIC'
AND ( c.`ARTIST` LIKE '%$theValue%' OR c.`TITLE` LIKE '%$theValue%')
OR (t.`ARTIST` LIKE '%$theValue%' OR t.`TRACK TITLE` LIKE '%$theValue%')
ORDER BY c.`RELEASEDATE` DESC
```